# can't modify buffer from pointer to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, buffer

i'm trying to fill a buffer using read function. my code look like this:

```
int open_read_file(char *path, char **buffer)
{
struct stat statbuf;
int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
int fc = 0;

if (fd < 0) {
    my_puterror("Cannot open this file\n");
    return 84;
}
if (stat(path, &statbuf) == -1)
    return 84;
*buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (statbuf.st_size + 1));
fc = read(fd, *buffer, statbuf.st_size);
if (fc < 0) {
    my_puterror("Cannot read this file\n");
    return 84; 
}
*buffer[fc] = '\0';
close(fd);
return 0;
}

int error_handler(int argc, char **argv, char **buffer)
{
if (argc < 3 || argc > 3) {
    my_puterror("Wrong argument\n");
    return 84;
}
if (my_getnbr(argv[2]) < 1 || my_getnbr(argv[2]) > 3) {
    my_puterror("Wrong argument\n");
    return 84;
}
if (my_str_isnum(argv[2]) == 0) {
    my_puterror("Wrong file type\n");
    return 84;
}
if (open_read_file(argv[1], buffer) == 84)
    return 84;
return 0;
}
```

i've got a segfault: (Invalid write of size 1) on (*buffer[fc] = '\0') of open_read_file() function.
i'm passing my buffer to error_handler() with this line:

```
if (error_handler(argc, argv, &buffer) == 84)
```

and my buffer is initialized as followed

```
char *buffer = NULL;
```

do somebody have an idea?

Comment: It's an issue with operator precedence. Try this `(*buffer)[fc]`. `buffer` points to a pointer to an array. You are using it as if it points to an array of pointers and dereference pointer number `fc`.

Comment: In general, instead of doing some icky `*my_pointertopointer` syntax inside the function, use a local variable `char* buf = malloc...` and do all operations on that pointer, then at the very end do `*buffer = buf;`.

Comment: you have defined `**buffer` which means that if you access `*buffer` (or `buffer[x]`) you get a pointer, not a char. After your `malloc()` you have memory to store a bunch of pointers, but no information yet. You'll have to do more `malloc()`s to request memory to store your strings. This is why the assignment to `*buffer[fc]` goes wrong. The address stored at `buffer[fc]` points into nowhere.

Comment: As @Lundin says, but also free the buffer on error.

Comment: @Gerhardh it's working thank's

Comment: Also: you could avoid the pointer to pointer by just making the function return a pointer (or: NULL on failure) , instead of the (meaningless) int.

Answer (score 0):

you should change somethings here:

```
1. char *buffer = NULL; -> 
char ** buffer = malloc(sizeof(char**));

2. 
if (error_handler(argc, argv, &buffer) == 84)
-> if (error_handler(argc, argv, buffer) == 84)
```

your problem with your declaration
char *buffer = NULL;
buffer is a pointer to char. &buffer is address of buffer (variable) , it isn't a pointer to point other char pointer (char **)

Comment: It seems a bit unnecessary. Also that malloc call should be `malloc(sizeof(char*))`, not `malloc(sizeof(char**))` (although they will be the same size).

Comment: thanks, that's right, but i think it it clear for newbie also :)

Comment: Just another question from a newbie, what would size of return if the item wasn't declared with a size, but malloced? as in

char * c;
malloc( c, 6 );
strcpy( c, "Hello");
strlen(c);